# trying to identify source of bin dir change or directory rename app restart

Tags: events, iis, logging, application-end

I am logging Application_End events (IIS 7).

My app occasionally generates this event with the following details in the shutdown message:

"Change Notification for critical directories" and "bin dir change or directory rename".

The recorded detail does not include the name of the file or directory that's the basis for this event firing.

I am using VB.Net to record the event in the Application log.

Please advise what must be in my code to request the file or directory name that's the basis for this event firing.  Without knowing what's being changed or renamed, it's difficult to further investigate the issue.

Comment: Without your code we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: I'm having this problem too! I suspect antivirus is messing with files in the bin dir-- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/05/14/asp-net-performance-issue-large-number-of-application-restarts-due-to-virus-scanning.aspx